# flutter pub get failed in macos

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

> Running "flutter pub get" in General... Resolving dependencies...
> (13.9s) Connection closed before full header was received pub get
> failed command:
> "/Users/zhangyicheng/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
> __deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
>
> pub env: {   "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/zhangyicheng/Developer/flutter",
> "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",   "PUB_CACHE":
> "/Users/zhangyicheng/.pub-cache", }
>
> exit code: 69

Comment: Sometimes, a restart of your machine will do or you can also check if you have any pending update for flutter

Answer (score 0):

Get a stronger and more stable connection, try running 'flutter clean' first.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I fixed this error.
It's because of the permission.

```
cd /usr/local
sudo chown -R YOUENAME:admin ./Flutter
sudo chown -R YOUENAME:admin ./Users/YOURNAME/.pub-cache
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).